# Audio using Yeti Mic does not work on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, audio

I am following [iPhone Core Audio Tutorial by Tim Bolstad](http://timbolstad.com/2010/03/17/core-audio-getting-started-pt3/). It works as expected. I can hear the audio successfully.

But when I plug-in USB Yeti Stereo Microphone by BlueMic on my MacMini. It does not produce the sound anymore.

Why is that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Great news! It turns out that the output (sound) is sent to the Yeti speaker.

I connect my speaker to Yeti's headphone output. Now I can hear the sound.